# Literary term for referring to a future event in the story line

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques

Is there a literary term for when an author refers to something that is going to happen later?

I am referring to two usages of this technique.

The first is when an author says "as will be explained later" or some variation there-of.

The second, which I am more interested in, is when the author says "before XYZ changed all of that" when XYZ is something that happens later in the story.

An example of the second usage is in Genesis 13:10, which refers to the destruction of Sodom before it occurs.

Comment: @Kris Thanks.  I'm not sure if the title was inaccurate or not, but I changed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term *foreshadowing* often is used in this context.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foreshadowing#Noun), it means “A literary device in which an author drops subtle hints about plot developments to come later in the story”.

If the hints are less than subtle – as in Genesis 13:10, which parenthetically remarks, “This was before the LORD destroyed Sodom and Gomorrah” – one might refer, somewhat oxymoronically, to *blatant foreshadowing*, or perhaps *premature [dénouement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9nouement#Noun)*.

Terms that suggest unsubtle foreshadowing include  *[announcing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/announce#Verb)* (“To give public notice, or first notice of; to make known; to publish; to proclaim”),  *[annunciating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annunciate#Verb)* (“To announce”), and  *[prefiguring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefigure#Verb)* (“To show or suggest ahead of time; to represent beforehand (often used in a Biblical context)”).

Terms more akin to foreshadowing include *[presage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presage#Verb)*, *[portend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portend#Verb)*, and perhaps *[augur](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/augur#Verb)*.

Comment: See also [Chekhov's gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun).

Comment: In a strictly religious context, I would call it a *prophecy* about a future event (a supernatural prediction of the future).

Comment: @BradC, yes, *[prophecy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prophecy)*,  “A prediction, especially one made by a prophet or under divine inspiration”, is a good related term.    But typically, prophecy may be something the author of a work writes *about* vs using it  to drop hints about future plot developments.

Comment: All in the eye of the beholder, I suppose. Those who view the Bible as actually divinely inspired would view the words of Genesis as "true" prophecy (since the "author" of scripture is believed to be God himself). Modern writers are probably better off not trying to claim that for their own work :)